# Using [Dependency] attribute with Prism Unity in WPF application

Tags: dependency-injection, prism, unity-container

I'm trying to use Property Injection with Prism Unity however in VS 2019 
the [Dependency] attribute is giving an error that it is not recognised.

I've included Prism.Unity and Prism.Ioc namespaces but still no joy.
Can anyone say what I'm missing

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `Unity` namespace (see [DependencyAttribute.cs](https://github.com/unitycontainer/abstractions/blob/master/src/Attributes/Annotation/DependencyAttribute.cs)):

```
using Unity;
```

(and, of course, a reference to the `Unity.Abstractions` package)